# Why can't I display a background image?

Tags: html, css

I guess my css has problems, but I cannot find them. How can I display this image as background?

```html
    <div style="
        background-image: url(https://www.marsha.com.hk/libs/img/Massage-landing 1906x810_R1-02.jpg);  
        width:100%;
            height:100vh;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        "></div>
```

I cannot display the image

Answer (score 4):

URLs cannot have literal spaces in them. Your `url()` is invalid, so the CSS parser drops it.

Encode the space as `%20`.

```html
    <div style="
        background-image: url(https://www.marsha.com.hk/libs/img/Massage-landing%201906x810_R1-02.jpg);  
        width:100%;
            height:100vh;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        "></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try to change the whitespace on the url with a %20, like this:
https://www.marsha.com.hk/libs/img/Massage-landing%201906x810_R1-02.jpg